# Typescript error: "Return type of exported function has or is using name <n> from external module <M> but cannot be named"

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

With Typescript 2.6.2, I have developed a function which returns an Observable. This function has been developed within a module that I have published as package named **my-package**.

The function is defined in the file **my-function.ts** as such

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export function myFunction() {
    return Observable.from([1,2,3]));
}
```

The module has its **index.ts** as such

```
import {myFunction} from './my-function';

export {myFunction};
```

Now I want to use **my-function** in a different project. Therefore I import **my-package** and then write a new function, **newFunction**, that uses **my-function** in a file which looks like

```
import {myFunction} from 'my-function';

export function newFunction() {
    return myFunction();
}
```

If I do so, when I try to compile this last file I get an error whose text is

*Return type of exported function has or is using name 'Observable' from external module "~/node_modules/rxjs/Observable" but cannot be named.*

In order to fix this problem, I have to change the code of **newFunction** as such

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import {myFunction} from 'my-function';

 export function newFunction(): Observable<any> {
     return myFunction();
 }
```

Is there a way to avoid the compiler problem without having to declare explicitly the return type of **newFunction**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message specifically mentions "name `Observable`", which is not within the scope of the module where `newFunction` is defined, which prevents compiler from generating type declaration file for that module.

To fix it, you only need to import that name - `Observable` - and nothing more. Just add this line to `newFunction` module:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

That's enough to enable the compiler to spell out inferred return type for `newFunction` in generated `.d.ts` file, you don't have to declare that return type explicitly.

Comment: I have added the return type explicitly since I have specified `"noUnusedLocals": true` in tsconfig.json - but this is probably a different story. I am wondering if it would make sense to allow the compiler to import what is needed (Observable in this case) silently, without having to force the explicit import, considering that the error message shows that the compiler knows everything (i.e. which class to import from which package). Thanks anyways